# c++ coding choose every case on switch code

Tags: c++, switch-statement

So im having a project and this is my code but i have a problem in this code and instead of choosing only one it choose every possible cases so help me and this is the code i also dont know how did that happen and im still looking for the reason why did that happen but maybe i need professional help so this is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char one, two, three, four;
    double a, b, c, d;



    cout << "What do you want to find on the square?" << endl;
    cout << "A. Area" << endl;
    cout << "B. Side" << endl;
    cout << "C. Diagonal" << endl;
    cout << "D. Perimeter" << endl;
    cin >> one ;
    one = toupper(one);
    switch (one)
        {
        case 'A':
            {   cout << "What is Given" << endl;
                cout << "S. Side" << endl;
                cout << "D. Diagonal" << endl;
                cout << "P. Perimeter" << endl;
                cin >> two;
                two = toupper(two);
                switch (two)
                    {   
                    case 'S':
                        {   
                            cout << "Enter Measure of the side." << endl;
                            cin >> a;
                            a= a*a;
                            cout << "The Answer is " << a << endl;

                        }
                    case 'D':
                        {
                            cout << "Enter Measure of the diagonal" << endl;
                            cin >> a;
                            a= pow( a/sqrt(2), 2);
                            cout << "The Answer is " << a << endl;

                        }
                    case 'P':
                        {
                            cout << "Enter measure of Perimeter" << endl;
                            cin >> c;
                            c= pow(c/4, 2);
                            cout << "The Answer is " << c << endl;
                        }
                    default :
                        {
                        }
                    }
            }
        }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need a `break` at the end of every `case`.

Comment: FYI, there's no need to put `{}` around the case code.

Comment: Glad this was asked because this is a common mistake made when first messing around with switch statements. As a tutor I see this happen quite a bit.

Comment: When you have a problem with a language feature you should check a good book or online reference, such as: [switch statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch)

Comment: I'm surprised I couldn't find other questions to make this a duplicate of.

Answer (score 5):

You need to

```
 break
```

after every case. Like this:

```
 case 'S':
      {   
          cout << "Enter Measure of the side." << endl;
          cin >> a;
          a= a*a;
          cout << "The Answer is " << a << endl;
          break;
      }
```

for every case. Or else it will go through all of the cases without breaking, which is what is happening in your case

Answer (score 2):

Add a break; at the end of each switch statement.

Example:

```
switch ( a ) {
case b:
  // Do something
  break;
default:
  // Do Something
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Switch operator will make whatever variable is in the switch parenthesis be searched for in all the cases found between the brackets and run the code in the situation that the 2 variables are ==. Given that you only want 1 of the cases to be analysed, a "break" must be inserted so that your code leaves the brackets completely after having found a case value that is equal to the variable found in the parenthesis of the switch operator.

```
switch (a) 
{
    case b:
    {
    ...
    }
    break;
    case c:
    {
    ...
    }
    break;

}
```

the break must be outside the case brackets, since the break code will make the thread exit out of the current bracket that the code is running in.

Comment: Doesn't matter where you put the `break`. It's just a matter of your preference.

Comment: wouldnt putting the break inside the case brackets cause the break to only exit the "case brackets" and not the "switch brackets"?

Comment: nope. For example, if you have an if statement inside a for loop - It doesn't matter if you have a `break` inside the `if` or outside the `if`, it eventually breaks out of the `for` loop. Similar is the case here.

Comment: @CodeBlocks: [The `break` terminates an enclosing `for`, `while`, or `switch` statement.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break) You can think of it as searching the enclosing scopes until it finds a valid one to bind to.

Comment: cool. Another issue though. whyy does it work outside? I mean i would guess that in the case of the if and for loop, since the break is outside the if statement, it should be read on every iteration of the for loop, hence exiting the for loop every time. Why is that not the case?

Comment: @CodeBlocks: Not sure I follow your question but a `break` in the body of a `for` loop will terminate the loop as soon as execution reaches the `break`. If it's inside an `if` block (inside a `for` loop) it will only terminate the loop when the test is true.

Comment: for (int x = 0; x<100; x++){if(x>200){cout<<"this will never happen";} break;}..... in this case, shouldn't the break code be executed every iteration of the for loop? hence only letting the for loop do 1 iteration...

Comment: @CodeBlocks: You're right, that will execute the body of the loop once, __not__ printing the message and then terminating the loop.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: agreed, so why is it different for the switch&case situation. switch (a) { case:b {....}break; case:c {...}break; } here it is exactly the same scenario as for the if and for loop, but the switch statement will not be exited after the first break if a!=b

Comment: im just pointing out that since the break is outside the if brackets and outside the case brackets, shouldn't the "break" code always be executed, hence always causing the for loop to exit after the first iteration, and always causing the switch to exit after the first break? I know that is not the case, but why not?

Comment: @CodeBlocks: Think of the `switch` as a jump table. Execution starts with the matching `case` label (or `default` if no labels match). It's a fancy computed `goto`.